# how to get the Soap Envelope response from the WCF client

Tags: wcf-client

I want to get the  request/response from the WCF consuming client as soap envelope. Is there any way to get it by adding the service reference in any of the c# application?.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your service reference and want to capture the actual SOAP message info you can do this:

You can use an message inspector and capture the SOAP message requests and responses:
[more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors)

or you can use system.diagnostics to log the information (not good for production usage, only for debuggin):
[message logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging)